# Next.js 13.4.1 get 404 for webpack.hot-update.json

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am getting a 404 error for http://localhost:3002/_next/static/webpack/cbfe56cfa390e6ae.webpack.hot-update.json when I run my next.js app

here is my next.config.js

```js
const isUnsafeEval =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : `'unsafe-eval'`;
const isStrictMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;

const csp = `
  default-src 'self';
  script-src 'self' ${isUnsafeEval} https://apis.google.com;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
  font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
  img-src 'self' https://lh3.googleusercontent.com;
  media-src 'self' ;
  connect-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com;
`;
`;

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: isStrictMode,

  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: csp.replace(/\n/g, ''),
          },
          {
            key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
            value: 'nosniff',
          },
          {
            key: 'X-Frame-Options',
            value: 'DENY',
          },
          {
            key: 'Referrer-Policy',
            value: ' strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
          },
          {
            key: 'Server',
            value: 'hello',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I don't do anything explicit with webpack

Every time i get this error: my terminal has `- warn Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload.` this message

tried clearing .next folder and rerunning all the npm install and npm run dev

Comment: Even when i remove all the contents of the config and restart the server, i still get those errors

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix to my issue here:

[NextJS issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43398)

TLDR: Clear the cache on your browser

Hope it helps you.